# Non commutative intersection over Maps

Tags: haskell, dictionary

How can I define function, that for each key of first map lookup a value of second map, apply some function to these 2 values and generate third map?

`∷ (α → Maybe β → γ) → Map k α → Map k β → Map k γ`

I played a little bit with some combinations of `unionWith`, `differenceWith` and `intersectionWith`, but stuck on mixing them with `lookup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is

```
foo :: (α → Maybe β → γ) → Map k α → Map k β → Map k γ
foo comb ma mb = Map.mapWithKey (\k a -> comb a (Map.lookup k mb)) ma
```

what you want?